# How do i navigate through images stored in mysql rather than displaying all of them?

Tags: php, mysql

This is my code but it displays all of the images saved in the database, i just want one to be displayed and the rest by using next and previous buttons. any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

```
<?php  
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM images";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die("bad request: $sql");
        $i = 0;
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        if($i%3 == 0) 
        {
            echo "<tr>";
        }
        echo"<td><img src='user_data/{$row['FILE_NAME']}' width=200 height=200></td>";
        if($i%3 == 2) {
            echo"</tr>";
        }
    }
 ?>
```

Comment: For one thing, do not select all the images (or at least not every single image blob) at once; for another, without an order specified there is no "next" or "previous".

Comment: `SELECT * FROM images ORDER BY FILE_NAME LIMIT 0,1` and increment or decrement the first number for next and prev.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use LIMIT and OFFSET in your query. It would look like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT file_name FROM images LIMIT 0,1";
```

This will get you 1 record, starting at record 0. So from that query you can build your pagination script. Just keep adding one to the offset (the first number in the LIMIT clause). Remember to filter the page number (make sure it’s an int).

Comment: Thats great! How do i add one to the offset?

Comment: You’ll need to get the offset value via POST or GET (to allow user interaction). So, $offset = filter_var($_GET[“offset”], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);. Then, use that variable in the query. Now, you can control the offset via that variable, so print a link at the bottom of the page incrementing the offset by one, like so: <a href=“?offset=<?=($offset + 1)?>”>Next</a>. You can also add some logic to warn the user if the offset variable is not a number (in addition to sanitizing it like in the code before).